# Highlight table row fetched from db with current day

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

With the code below I am fetching a table from my database. The first column had a calendar and I would like to know if possible to highlight the row of the table that contains the current day.

I am also displaying the current day with this script:

```
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
         echo " Italy: " . date("h:i:sa");
         echo " day " . date("d/m/Y") . "<br>";
          ?>
```

--- TABLE CODE ---

```
     <?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM trip"; 
                $result = mysql_query($query);

                echo "<table >"; // start a table tag in the HTML

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
                echo "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Flight'] . "</td>
                        </tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                }

                echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
                mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection

            ?>
```

---css CODE--

```
table
{
font-family: verdana;

color: white;
background: #003366;
text-align:center;
font-size:16px;
border-collapse: collapse; 

}
tr   {

padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
font-size:16px;

}

tr:hover{

color:#003366;
background: white;

}
```

---ADDING CLASS .TODAY

`.today
    {
    font-family: verdana;
    background: red;
    color: #003366;
    }`

Comment: Append a CSS class to the row.

Comment: What is the formatted output of `$row['Day']`?

Comment: I have on my css this which highlight the row in white since the background is blue but how to automatically highlight the row based on the current day?

Comment: You would need to use a conditional statement and check if the row equals the said day.

Comment: @gigi It would be helpful if you answered the question from above.

Comment: @RhapX, I am not sure I know what means: 
 
What is the formatted output of $row['Day']... I have a css for the table and I am fatching the data of the database with the code above, the output its simply a table with no borders that contains all the data that are into the database

Comment: @gigi You don't have to re-post your question - we get what you're asking. Just want to know what the output is of the `$row['Day']` - meaning, what is the format of the date? For instance, `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: yes thats correct, the format is YYYY-MM-DD, even though I would like to be DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: did you check my updated answer and comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Flight'] . "</td>
</tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}
```

with:

```
if ($row['Day'] ==  date("Y-m-d") ) {
    echo '<tr class="today">';
} else {
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Flight'] . "</td>
</tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}
```

and add class `today` to your css file.

Sorry I can't debug this, but I think you've got an idea

Comment: I added class today with background color red and changed the above code as suggested but still does not seems to read the property of the class.

Comment: All looks working but same as before. the row does not get highlighted.., maybe something wrong in my css? I posted it above

Comment: Actually I tested this code using Country and its works, so must be something with the date format

Comment: I've asked to show HTML generated, but you only show php code. so what is your HTML generated???

Comment: sorry I am not sure what you mean. the pages are all php. I can give you the link of the site: www.followmytrip.net

Comment: check my updated answer, just change date format then to `date("Y-m-d")`

Comment: and by the way there is no `.today` in your css on the website

Comment: css in in stylesheet css. If there was no css I was not able to see the changes with another column. But as I sayd if I dont use the date and I use country for exemple, the row gets highllight in red, that means the css is working

Comment: what are you talking about??? I checked your CSS file on your website and there is no .today section and did you implement my last changes to your code???

Comment: Hi, I implemented your code and is working. The css is there, I also post it above. I added the class .today. Why you say is not there?. If it was not there the code wont be able to work.....right?

Comment: no, it is not rigth, if you assign any clas to html elements, and those classe are not declared - browser don`t care and just default design applied to the element. just checked site http://www.followmytrip.net/  there is no .today declared in your stylesheet.css fil. and I am pretty sure you didn`t implement my changes. so to prove that did just replace to this fragment `if ($row['Day'] ==  date("Y-m-d") ) {
    echo '<tr class="today">';
} else {
    echo "<tr clas="nottoday">";
}`

Comment: The changes are not online, thats why you cant see it. I think this is the issue. I am going to upload the changes now. I worked in local.

Comment: so what is the reason to give me a link to some website, that is not based on my or even your code??

Comment: You right, i sent you the link just to make the idea clear and i forgot i did not upload all the changes. sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the mysql API, I am going to assume this is an existing legacy application. If it's not, I'd highly advise that you use the mysqli/PDO API and prepared statements. The sooner you do this the better and you will be much happier in the future about your decision to leave mysql behind.
In regards to your question, you can do this by formatting the existing date/timestamp and comparing it with the PHP `DateTime` class.

**PHP:**

```
$today = new DateTime('today'); // create new DT object representing today

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $dbDate = new DateTime($row['Day']); // converts database date to DT object
    $dbDate = $dbDate->format('Y-m-d'); // format as only date, remove time
    echo ($dbDate == $today) ? "<tr><td class=\"today\">" . $row['Day'] . "</td>" :
    "<tr><td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Flight'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.today {
  //the style you want//
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, regarding this solution I get an errot in the third line you posten on the square parentesis: $today = new DateTime['today']; // create new DT object representing today

Comment: Updated but now i got problem with  Undefined variable: row and undefined constant YYYY and mm and dd --- maybe something wrong with the day format? -- IN my database the format is DATE and not DATETIME, something connected with this?

Comment: Oops, forgot some apostrophes on the line above and should have been parenthesis instead of brackets. Should be fixed.

Comment: no errors but also nothing happen, i am trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Use loop through the table and find if cell has current day. And if it has then use jquery to highlight the cell. You can do like this:

```
 var d = new date();
 table.find('tr td').each(function(d){
   if($(this).text() == d) {
     $(this).css("background", "red");
   }
 });
```